# How to route the same verb to different actions on a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a task_list model that has some actions like archive and destroy. I want to route them like this:

```
resources :task_lists, only: [:create, :update] do
    member do
      delete '' => 'task_lists#archive'
      delete 'destroy' => 'task_lists#destroy'
    end
end
```

but `rake routes` gives same route for both of them.

```
             DELETE   /api/0.0/task_lists/:id(.:format)    task_lists#archive {:format=>:json}
   task_list DELETE   /api/0.0/task_lists/:id(.:format)    task_lists#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

so what can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
delete 'task_lists/:id/destroy(.:format)', :to => 'task_lists#destroy', :as => :destroy_task

delete 'task_lists/:id(.:format)', :to => 'task_lists#archive', :as => :archive_task
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It worked.  but I want to find out that is there any way to define it in `member` block ?